Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}dx$
Working about the field generated by a ring-shaped source in a near-field approximation, I met this integral :
$$I(k,a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}dx$$
We can consider that $k<<1$ and $a>>1$ (both $a,k\in\mathbb{R}$)
EDIT 3 : Cleared most of the post to have it easier to read and reflect recent progress
Using symmetries,
$$I(k,a) = 4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}dx$$
Now adressing the imaginary part
\begin{align}\Im{(I(k,a))} &= -4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin{\left(k\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}\right)}}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}dx\\&=-4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m k^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}(1+a^2\sin^2(x))^\frac{2m}{2}dx\\&=-4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m k^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\binom{m}{n}a^{2n}\sin^{2n}(x)dx\\&=-4\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m k^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\binom{m}{n}a^{2n}\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\\&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{2n}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n n!}\underbrace{\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m k^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}}_{J(n,k)}\end{align}
I used the value of Wallis' integrals and WolframAlpha gives me
$$J(n,k) = (-1)^n 2^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}k^{\frac{1}{2}+n}\sqrt{\pi}J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(k)$$
and used the equivalent for $x\approx 0$ of Bessel function:
$$J_{\alpha}(x)\approx \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\alpha} $$
So $$J(n,k) \approx \frac{(-1)^n 2^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}k^{2n+1}\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2})}$$
And using $\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2}) = \frac{(2n+2)!\sqrt{\pi}}{4^{n+1}(n+1)!}$
$$J(n,k) \approx \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)! 2^{n+\frac{3}{2}}k^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}$$
Finally,
\begin{align}\Im{(I(k,a))} &=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{2n}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n n!}J(n,k)\\&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{2n}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n n!}\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)! 2^{n+\frac{3}{2}}k^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\\&=-\sqrt{2}\pi k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{(2n)!(n+1)!}{n!^3(2n+2)!}\left(\frac{ka}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2n}\\&=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\pi k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n!)^2}\left(\frac{ka}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2n}\end{align}
According to WolframAlpha :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n!)^2}\left(\frac{ka}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2n} = {}_1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},-\frac{a^2k^2}{2}\right)$$
And using hypergeometric functions tables
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n!)^2}\left(\frac{ka}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\pi J_1(\sqrt{2}ak)H_0{(\sqrt{2}ak)}+J_1{(\sqrt{2}ak)}(2-\pi H_1{(\sqrt{2}ak)})\right)$$
In the end :
$$\Im{(I(k,a))} = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\pi k\left(\pi J_1(\sqrt{2}ak)H_0{(\sqrt{2}ak)}+J_1{(\sqrt{2}ak)}(2-\pi H_1{(\sqrt{2}ak)})\right)$$
The $\Re{(I(k,a))}$ is even more work (especially due to half-integer powers of $\sin$) so I will split my questions into different questions, but if you want to give it a try, feel free !
Thanks for any further help, I will post complete answer once the real part is done

The integrand is real and finit on the real interval $\Rightarrow$ the integral is real

Couldn't you just substitute $u=1 + a^2\sin^2(x)$? Or even $u^2=1 + a^2\sin^2(x)$?

forgot the $i$ sign in the exponant .. fixed now :).

didn't work too much to me to do $u^2= 1+a^2\sin^2(x)$, maybe i need to push it further

Why did we get $-1$ as a real part ?

That's what got plotting on Desmos. You don't find the same ?

Why not split the fraction and integrate using the elliptic integral of the second kind? Also, it seems that integral can be taken over $\int_0^\frac\pi2$ and scaling.

Yes I know I could do that, actually I started from $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-k\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2x}}dx$ and splitted it because I could express $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2x}}dx \approx \ln(8a)$ using scaling and elleptic integral techniques, otherwise didn't manage to do that on the one from the post.

You can convert your integral into a contour one by doing $z=e^{ix}$:
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\exp(-ik\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2x})-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2x}}\,\mathrm dx=\oint_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\exp\left[-ik\sqrt{1-\dfrac{a^2}{4}\left(z-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^2}\right]-1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{a^2}{4}\left(z-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^2}}\,\dfrac{\mathrm dz}{iz},\ a\neq 0$$
The roots have real branch points,
$$
\begin{matrix}
z_1=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a}; &\enspace z_2=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a}\\
z_3=-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a}; &\enspace z_4=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a},
\end{matrix}
$$
of which only $z_2, z_4\in\text{Int}(|z|=1)$ and, at most, when $a\to\infty$, $z_1,z_3\in |z|=1$, but we'll ignore that. Furthermore, $z=\infty$ is not a branch point since $f\left(\dfrac{1}{\zeta}\right)=f(\zeta)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)\neq 0$, where $f(z)$ is the function inside the roots. The only possible pole is the origin. The branch points aren't singularities because the limit is finite:
$$\lim_{z\to z_i}\dfrac{\exp(-ik\sqrt{f(z)})-1}{\sqrt{f(z)}}=-ik\enspace\forall z_i$$
So I'd suggest doing a Laurent series of
$$\small\dfrac{\exp\left[-ik\sqrt{1-\dfrac{a^2}{4}\left(z-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^2}\right]-1}{iz\sqrt{1-\dfrac{a^2}{4}\left(z-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^2}}$$
all the while avoiding the branch cuts. I'd need help on this last step and we'd obtain the final result for the original integral.

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$
I noticed the original integral can be expressed as a double integral,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^k\exp\left(-iy\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}\right)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
If we are permitted to interchange order of integration we have
$$\int_0^k\int_0^{2\pi}\exp\left(-iy\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}\right)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy,$$
which can be solved by employing the same technique:
$$\int_0^k\oint_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\exp\left[-ik\sqrt{1-\dfrac{a^2}{4}\left(z-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^2}\right]}{iz}\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy.$$
At least the integrand isn't as complex but the integral is difficult either way.

$$\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{\exp \left(-i k \sqrt{1+a^2 \sin ^2(x)}\right)-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2 \sin ^2(x)}} \, dx=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } -\frac{2 i (-1)^m e^{\frac{i m \pi }{2}} k^{1+m} \pi  \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{m}{2};1;-a^2\right)}{\Gamma (2+m)}=\\i \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } -\frac{(2 k \pi ) \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n (1)_m (1)_{\frac{m}{2}+n}\right)
   \left(\left(\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}\right)^n (-i k)^m\right)}{\sqrt{1+a^2} \left((1)_{\frac{m}{2}} (1)_n (2)_m\right) (n! m!)}$$
The double sum can be expressed by Srivastava - Daoust function.
If $a\to \infty$ then the asymptotic we have:
$$\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{\exp \left(-i k \sqrt{1+a^2 \sin ^2(x)}\right)-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2 \sin ^2(x)}} \, dx\approx-\frac{4 \gamma }{a}-\frac{2 i \pi }{a}-\frac{2 \ln (4)}{a}-\frac{4 \ln (a k)}{a}$$
EDITED:
If $a\to \infty$ then the asymptotic we have:
$\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{\exp \left(-i k \sqrt{1+a^2 \sin ^2(x)}\right)-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2 \sin ^2(x)}} \, dx=\\\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{4 \sqrt{2} \left(-1+e^{-\frac{i k \sqrt{2+a^2-a^2 \cos (8 t)}}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{2+a^2-a^2
   \cos (8 t)}} \, dt=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\mathcal{L}_k\left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{4 \sqrt{2} \left(-1+e^{-\frac{i k \sqrt{2+a^2-a^2 \cos (8 t)}}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{2+a^2-a^2 \cos (8 t)}} \,
   dt\right](s)\right](k)=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \mathcal{L}_k\left[\frac{4 \sqrt{2} \left(-1+e^{-\frac{i k \sqrt{2+a^2-a^2 \cos (8 t)}}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{2+a^2-a^2 \cos (8 t)}}\right](s) \,
   dt\right](k)=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} -\frac{8}{-2 i s^2+\sqrt{2} s \sqrt{2+a^2-a^2 \cos (8 t)}} \, dt\right](k)=\\\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{2 i \pi  \sqrt{\left(1+s^2\right) \left(1+a^2+s^2\right)}}{\left(1+s^2\right) \left(1+a^2+s^2\right)}-\frac{4 K\left(-a^2\right)}{s}-\frac{4 s \Pi
   \left(-\frac{a^2}{1+s^2}|-a^2\right)}{1+s^2}\right](k)=\\-4 K\left(-a^2\right)+\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{2 i \pi }{\sqrt{\left(1+s^2\right) \left(1+a^2+s^2\right)}}-\frac{4 s \Pi \left(-\frac{a^2}{1+s^2}|-a^2\right)}{1+s^2}\right](k)$
using a->Infinty:
$-\frac{2 i \pi }{\sqrt{\left(1+s^2\right) \left(1+a^2+s^2\right)}}\approx-\frac{3 i \pi }{4 a^5 \sqrt{1+s^2}}+\frac{i \pi }{a^3 \sqrt{1+s^2}}-\frac{2 i \pi }{a \sqrt{1+s^2}}$
$\frac{4 s \Pi \left(-\frac{a^2}{1+s^2}|-a^2\right)}{1+s^2}\approx\frac{4 s \log (a)}{a s^2+a}$
then we have:
$-4 K\left(-a^2\right)+\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{3 i \pi }{4 a^5 \sqrt{1+s^2}}+\frac{i \pi }{a^3 \sqrt{1+s^2}}-\frac{2 i \pi }{a \sqrt{1+s^2}}-\frac{4 s \log (a)}{a+a s^2}\right](k)=\\-\frac{3 i \pi  J_0(k)}{4 a^5}+\frac{i \pi 
   J_0(k)}{a^3}-\frac{2 i \pi  J_0(k)}{a}-4 K\left(-a^2\right)-\frac{4 \cos (k) \log (a)}{a}$
where:
$J_0$ is  Bessel function of the first kind,
$K$ is  the complete elliptic integral of the first kind,
$\Pi$ is the complete elliptic integral of the third kind,
$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}$ is Inverse Laplace Transform.

Sorry for late answer, was trying to rederive it by myself. In the end, it worked pretty poorly for me in terms of numerical values (I have $k\approx 0.01$ and $5<a<100$). I then removed the accepted answer tag, so new people may have a try, sorry :(
